# Are there any side effect of using to many static function?

Tags: java, playframework

Currently i`m interesting in play framework because this framework promise faster development.

When i see the code, there are so many static code. even the controller declared as static function. Thus all the code that called inside static function must be static right?

My question is, is this approach is right? are there any side effect of using to many static function?

Comment: static methods can call non static methods of instance that are passed as arguments or in static fields, or objects they create.  It can't call non-static method of the same class without an instance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Couple of things about static methods in an object oriented language: Let me try to explain the problems if you choose to have all static methods.

Using all static functions may not be idiomatic in an Object oriented language. 
You cannot override static functions in a subclass. Therefore you lose the ability to do runtime polymorphism by overriding.

The variables that you define all become class variables automatically (since all your methods are static), so essentially you do not have any state associated with the instance.

Static methods are difficult to Mock. You might need frameworks like PowerMock to do the mocking for you. So testing becomes difficult.

Design becomes a bit complex as you won't be able to create immutable classes as you really only have the class and no instance. So designing thread-safe classes becomes difficult.

Comment: For testing, Play Framework use JUNIT4 and Selenium. I think that sufficient to create unit testing and regression testing

Comment: "So designing thread-safe classes becomes difficult" based on your comment, it`s not good to use play framework in enterprise application?

Comment: Let me clarify. Designing a class for immutability is a way of designing a thread-safe class without having to introduce synchronization. Ofcourse when you need a change of state to the object then you have to create a new instance of the class. For an example look at the String class. But if your methods are all static and all you have is class variables, then an immutable class is out of question, as there is no instance. I did not mean to say that a class with only static methods cannot be thread safe.

Comment: @indrap. Good OO design ensures decoupled classes. A good way of doing that is to inject your dependencies. Testing classes in isolation is a good way of writing unit tests. IN order to test classes in isolation you need to mock the dependencies. Since static methods cannot be overridden you need a bytecode manipulating library like powermock to do the mocking for you. This is what I meant when I said testing becomes difficult.

Comment: I see you point,Thank yo.  As you see on Peter Lawrey comment, seem my problem in using static function could be avoided by using IOC.

Comment: "Some Java developers might want to scream in pain and agony now that "Static methods in 
a controller are not threadsafe!". However, the Controller is bytecode enhanced in order to 
make certain calls threadsafe, so the developer has not to worry about such issues. If you 
are interested in knowing more, you might want to check the class play.classloading.
enhancers.ControllerEnhancer" This is part of comment taken from Play Framework Cookbook page 15 that show the creator have been addressed tread safety issue properly.

Comment: Imo, this statement "so essentially you do not have any state associated with the instance." can be "You have only one state associated with all instances."

Answer (score 17):

This question has been asked in a similar way previously. The simple answer is that Play uses statics where it is sensible.

The HTTP model is not an OO model. HTTP requests themselves are stateless, and therefore, static methods allow access to controllers as functional requests from client code.

The Model classes on the other hand are pure OO, and as a result are not static heavy.
Some of the utility methods, such as findAll or findById are static, but these again are not statefull, and are utility methods on the class. I would expect this in a standard OO model anyway.

Therefore, I don't think there is any risk in doing things in the way Play expects. It may look odd, because it challenges the norm, but it does so for sound reasons.

Comment: This is the correct answer as it pertains specifically to the Play Framework.

Comment: From the Play Framework cookbook page 15, it show that the creator addressed this issue very well see( play.classloading.
enhancers.ControllerEnhancer)

Comment: Indeed he did. Guillaume is very smart guy, and the Play team have designed the structure of Play very well.

Answer (score 1):

To elaborate on my comment.

static methods can call non-static methods provided you have an instance of something.

```
class A {
   public void nonStaticMethod() { }

   public static void staticMethod(String text) {
      // calls non-static method on text
      text.length();
      // calls non-static method on new Object
      new Object().hashCode();
      // calls non static method on a instance of A
      new A().nonStaticMethod();
   }
}
```

Comment: i see you point, thank you. I can use google guice to create object instance then use the non static function in controller

Answer (score -3):

Yes there is a side effect of using too many static functions or variables. **You should avoid unnecessary static declarations.**

Because static members always creates a memory space once the class is loaded in the JRE. Even if you don't create the object of the class it will occupy the memory.

Comment: Since controller use static class thus all function or class that called inside controller must be static to.. I think in this case the static usage is quite necessary.

Comment: This answer is incorrect.  A static method uses no more or less space than an instance method.  And it makes no difference whether or not an instance of the class is made.

Comment: The OP is asking about static _functions_, not static _fields_. Static fields will allocate space as soon as the class is loaded, whereas instance fields will not allocate until an instance is created (however, memory allocated for a static field is only allocated once, but instance fields allocate additional memory for _every_ instance). As @stephenc notes, it makes no difference for methods.

Comment: The only difference between static methods and non-static (instance) methods behind the scenes is that an extra, hidden parameter (this) is passed to instance methods and that instance methods might be called using an indirect dispatch (if virtual). There is no additional code space taken.